# Using C++ Classes to handle commonly used parameters

Tags: c++, class, parameters, class-design

My team works on an HTTP web server in C++. The codebase has aged over time, and has a widespread problem of 12+ parameters being passed to every function.

A fake example: We need to build a Car, but in order to do that, we have the following function:

```
MaybeBuildCar(engine_params, steering_params, interior_params, fuel_params, available_inventory, parts, &debug);
```

Someone on our team has proposed that we create a wrapper `CarBuilder` class whose constructor takes in the params and "stateful" objects like `available_inventory`, then has a separate function for `BuildCar` as follows:

```
CarBuilder car_builder(engine_params, steering_params, interior_params, fuel_params, available_inventory, &debug);

auto car = car_builder.BuildCar(parts);
```

Personally, I don't see much value in having a class with a single public function that is always called. We'll always need these parameters, and we'll always need the parts, so this just adds more steps to build the car. It could even add confusion, as now a user of `CarBuilder` must know to both construct it and call `BuildCar`.

Admittedly, this simplifies our helper functions within `car_builder.cc`, as they also require passing these params, but to me that's misusing what a class is for: maintaining state.

Is creating this CarBuilder a misuse of the class, or is simply cleaning up function signatures a valid use? Does anyone have any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Of course having such a function in the first place is quite a smell. As all of these `_params` seem to be semantically linked, I would define a `struct` which holds them all, and then use that to pass everything around. Caveat: I have no idea how and where all those `_params` come from, so YMMV.

Comment: @lopho Just curious, in what way is the BuildCar function a smell? Unfortunately, combining these params, isn't a great option, but I will consider it.

Comment: It hints at a function/class with too much responsibility. At best a function should do one thing. Staying in the Car analogy, you could compare it to an assembly line with only one station.It also hints at what I have already mentioned, that all those `_params` seem to belong together in the first place. Of course a lot of parameters can be reasonable, as always it depends.

Comment: I see. My teammate has actually proposed creating different functions like AddEngine, AddMuffler, etc, but they all need to be called either way, so to me it feels superfluous and makes usage a bit confusing for other engineers. Am I incorrect in thinking this?

Comment: I depends what these functions do. If they are just a setter, then maybe params should be passed as constructor arguments. But if they actually do something more complex and not necessarily related (adding a muffler has no overlap with installing and calibrating headlights), it is a good idea to split them in separate functions.

Comment: I see. Even if they're always called, you'd still want different public calls for InstallWindshield, BuildEngine, etc? Is there ever a worry about user confusion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228602/discussion-between-lopho-and-donutgaz).

Comment: A builder class is a good idea in this case. **Listen to your teams members when they suggest good practices**. Seriously if you have more that 12 parameters, it is clearly unmaintainable. In the future, you will need to add a display, lateral airbags and the list continue. Reading a book on **design patterns** might be a good idea. With a builder, you can specify any required options and then call `Build` when ready. If you build many different cars, then **prototypes** or **factories** might also be useful. Also, you need small functions to be able to reuse most code for different cars.

Answer (score 1):

Minimizing function parameters can be a blessing for heavily used functions in a performance-sensitive environment:

If you pass 6 references to a function, that is 6 pointer copies pushed to the stack;
If you pass a single `CarBuilder`, it is one "reference-that-contains-6-other-references".

It depends on your situation.

Answer (score 1):

you could define a class that contains all parameters and in each function just passed this object.

```
struct CarComponent
{
 public:
    EngineParams engine_params;
    SteeringParams steering_params;
    InteriorParams interior_params;
    FuelParams fuel_params;
    AvailableInventory available_inventory
};

MaybeBuildCar(car_component);
other_function(car_component);
```

Advantage:

- Function's signature is decoupled from changing members of the struct (CarComponent). easy to **change**.
- Refactor all the parameters in each function with a specific object. it prevents **repetition** and it becomes **easier to read** the code.